# why use ThreadPool has advantages over thread-based approach?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

My textbook says:

> should you need to run hundreds or thousands of concurrent I/O-bound
>   operations, a thread-based approach consumes hundreds or thousands of
>   MB of memory purely in thread overhead.

and

> when running multiple long-running tasks in parallel, performance can
>   suffer, then a thread-based approach is better

I'm confused, what's the difference between a non-threadpool thread's overhead and threadpool thread's? How overhead related to I/O-bound?

And finally, why thread-based approach (for example, use `new Thread(runMethod).Start()`) is better for long-running tasks?

Comment: This is a little too broad and disjointed. There also seems to be a little bit of missing context. I think instead of asking a question like this, maybe its best to research tasks, threads and the thread-pool

Comment: _"why thread based approach(for example,use Task.Run()) is better for long-running tasks"_ That is _not_ a "thread-based approach" in the sense that Task.Run() will use the Threadpool. "Thread-based" would be `Thread t = new Thread(runMethod); t.Start();`

Comment: _"when running multiple long-running tasks in parallel,performance can suffer, then a thread-based approach is better"_ Think of it this way: You have n Threads in the pool, ready to take on tasks. Now if you block one of them with a long running task, you only have n-1 left to take on tasks. If you create a separate Thread for the long running task, you still have n. If the additional thread is long running, then the additional overhead can be accepted.

Comment: _"How overhead related to I/O-bound?"_ On a I/O bound Task, there is no overhead, because [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The _task_ waiting for IO will release the thread and may (or may not) continue on the same or another thread when the IO is ready. (Of course, I am assuming you `await` some async IO method)

Comment: @Fildor so for the first question, why a Task-based approach can reduce the thread overhead? for executing same I/O-bound operations, which is the same job for Task-based approach and thread-based approach, why Task-based approach is better?

Comment: As I wrote, there is no thread in Task-based. You are waiting on some OS-dependent async mechanism that is not using a thread at all. Therefore, no overhead. I also linked a blog from Stephen Cleary about this. He explains it in detail and _way_ better than I ever could.

Comment: Its to do with the way the operating system handles IO requests and IO Completion ports and how the async and await pattern is able to give back the threadpool resources until its needed again. However once again this is way too broad, you really need to start looking at blogs and online resources.

Comment: @Fildor isn't that `Task.Run()` uses a secondary thread which is in Threadpool to execute the delegate, how could it be considered as 'no thread' involved?

Comment: You don't Task.Run in that case. If you do, you force the use of a threadpool thread which will be released while waiting for IO. If you mix both CPU-Bound and IO-Bound, that's a different question and also not recommended. It's all in Stephen's Blog. Also mind, that you might end up in a different context before and after the IO, depending on your implementation.

Comment: `ThreadPool` has a limited number of reusable threads. This threads are used for tasks (e.g. `TaskRun`). A task that executes for a longer period of time would block a thread that couldn't be reused for another `Task`. So in order to always have enough `ThreadPool` threads available (e.g. for `async/await`, Parallel Linq etc.), you should use `ThreadPool` independent thread for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ThreadPool` has a limited number of reusable threads. This threads are used for tasks (e.g. `Task.Run`). A task that executes for a longer period of time would block a thread so that it couldn't be reused for another `Task`. So in order to always have enough `ThreadPool` threads available (e.g. for async/await, Parallel Linq etc.), you should use `ThreadPool` independent threads for this kind of tasks.
You do this by using the `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action, TaskCreationOptions)` (or any other overload that accepts a `TaskCreationOptions` object) and then pass in the parameter `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. `LongRunning` forces a new thread that is independent from the `ThreadPool`.

So for all long running and IO based tasks, like reading a file or database, you are supposed to use `ThreadPool` independent threads by calling `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAction(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`. You don't need `new Thread(runMethod).Start()` at all.

`ThreadPool` threads are more resource efficient since they are reusable. So when retrieving `ThreadPool` threads, they are already created. Creating new threads is always resource expensive. They need to be registered, call stacks must be created, locals must be copied, etc. This is why when considering performance, reusable threads are preferable choice, as long as the workload is lightweight (short running).